# can you create a twilio twiml bin in python?

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-python

Is there a way to create a Twiml Bin through the Twilio API in Python?

I'm trying to automate the process of setting up numbers that behave a certain way, but I want them to be fully integrated into the web interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no CRUD API's for TwimlBins. TwimlBins do support [mustache templates](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/tutorials/twiml-bins#nice-mustache) to pass in parameters. An alternative is to use the [Twilio Studio Flows API](https://www.twilio.com/blog/automate-flow-deployments-studio-rest-api-v2-generally-available) or the [Twilio Functions API](https://www.twilio.com/changelog/new-serverless-api-deploy-functions-and-assets).